# Apache 403 Forbidden Error - Can't access webserver

Tags: 11.10, apache2

Yesterday my apache server decided to don't run anymore and I don't now why. Every virtual host displays an 403-Error-Message like the following I copied from the log file:

```
[error] [client 127.0.0.1] (13)Permission denied: access to / denied
```

I think rights are set correctly, I prooved with ls -al /home/...
And actually I didn't changed anything in the configuration:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
ServerName webprojekte
DocumentRoot /home/tarea/Webprojekte/work
<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
</Directory>
<Directory /home/tarea/Webprojekte/work/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride None
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all
</Directory>
ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
<Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
    AllowOverride None
    Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>

ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

# Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
# alert, emerg.
LogLevel warn

CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

Alias /doc/ "/usr/share/doc/"
<Directory "/usr/share/doc/">
    Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
    Allow from 127.0.0.0/255.0.0.0 ::1/128
</Directory>
```

By the way phpmyadmin is still working correctly. Thank you helping me!

Comment: Please post `ls -ld /`

Comment: Related: http://askubuntu.com/questions/14301/apache-symlinked-to-home-directory-permission-errors/14364#14364

Answer (score 2):

It is not the configuration, but the file permissions themselves. You need to `chmod` your web root directories to 755 and web files to 664.

A far better solution is to use the user module in apache, which allows user to host files inside a public_html folder in home directory.

for further information see:

[Apache symlinked to home directory - Permission Errors](https://askubuntu.com/questions/14301/apache-symlinked-to-home-directory-permission-errors/14364#14364)

Comment: chmoding the files directory did't work. Nothing changed ...