# VirtualHost and 403 Forbidden problem with Apache

Tags: 10.10, apache2

I have the exactly same problem as in [403 Forbidden Error when accessing enabled virtual host](https://askubuntu.com/questions/2835/403-forbidden-error-when-accessing-enabled-virtual-host), but I tried the provided solution and still receiving 403 Forbidden, my site is called **project**, and it's cofiguration file in */etc/apache2/sites-available* is the following:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerAdmin webmaster@reweb
ServerName www.online.project.com
ErrorLog /logs/project-errors.log

DocumentRoot /home/joarobles/Zend/workspaces/DefaultWorkspace7/online.project.com.ar/public
<Directory /home/joarobles/Zend/workspaces/DefaultWorkspace7/online.project.com.ar>
    Order Deny,Allow
    Allow from all
    Options Indexes
</Directory>
```

Tried to change the owner of */home/joarobles/Zend/workspaces/DefaultWorkspace7/online.cobico.com.ar* to **www:data:www-data** with recursion, but still getting this error in **project-errors.log**:

```
[Mon Jan 31 01:26:01 2011] [crit] [client 127.0.0.1] (13)Permission denied: /home/joarobles/.htaccess pcfg_openfile: unable to check htaccess file, ensure it is readable
```

Any idea? Thanks!

Comment: I'm a bit confused because the owner of "/var/www" is root, shouldn't it be "apache" or something like that?

Comment: What are the full permissions of /var/www and /home/joarobles/.htaccess ?  Can you do an `ls -ld` of both?   Something like `drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 ` is OK for /var/www because the www-data user still has read access, which it needs to display content.

Comment: @Joaquin by default it uses `root` from the default install.  you'd need to modify the system's files to use a different user/group.

Comment: It's root because the webserver does not always have to write to it, static files or scripts which do not need to modify files.

Comment: Here is a similar post http://askubuntu.com/questions/2835/403-forbidden-error-when-accessing-enabled-virtual-host/14370#14370

Comment: Here is a similar post : http://askubuntu.com/questions/2835/403-forbidden-error-when-accessing-enabled-virtual-host/14370#14370

Answer (score 4):

You need to have Read and Execute permissions on your home folder. If you do `sudo chmod o+rx /home/joarobles` This error should then be resolved.

Answer (score 1):

Try to insert `<directory />` tags before your `<directory>` tags of your web root.

```
...
DocumentRoot /home/joarobles/Zend/workspaces/DefaultWorkspace7/online.project.com.ar/public
    <Directory />
       Options FollowSymLinks
       AllowOverride None
    </Directory>
<Directory /home/joarobles/Zend/workspaces/DefaultWorkspace7/online.project.com.ar>
 ...
```

It might help.